# Is there a difference between $\frac{|{\mathrm{d}y}|}{\mathrm{d}x}$ and $\biggr|\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\biggr|$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

***Problem:***

Is there a difference between:

> $$\frac{|{\mathrm{d}y}|}{\mathrm{d}x}$$**AND**
>   $$\biggr|\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\biggr|$$

Please explain using valid arguments.

I found it in a physics book but I was unable to understand it. Of course in the physics textbook it was $\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}$ instead of $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$.

Comment: See, getting downvotes takes lesser time than getting upvotes. What are the downvotes for anyway?

Comment: The first notation does not appear to be standard. Can you provide a sensible intance of usage, if not a definition?

Comment: @YourAverageEuler Plase give some example of what you mean exactly with the notation $\frac{|{\mathrm{d}y}|}{\mathrm{d}x}$

Comment: @gimusi For the sake of example, if $v$ is velocity then do $\frac{|dv|}{dt}$ and $\biggr|\frac{dv}{dt}\biggr|$ imply something different?

Comment: with |dv| do you mean the speed derivative?

Comment: @gimusi $v$ is velocity, not speed

Comment: ok but with $\frac{|d\vec v|}{dt}$ do you mean the derivative of the speed?

Comment: @gimusi  Dont know. $\biggr|\frac{dv}{dt}\biggr|$ is the modulus of accelaration, which is $\frac{dv}{dt}$.

Comment: Also in this case those are two completely different things. Think about, as an example, to a circular motion at constant speed.

Comment: Instead of saying just “a physics book”, it would be more useful to say exactly which book you refer to.

Comment: @YourAverageEuler posted. My guess is hes trying to distuish between speed/velocity and distance/displacement.

Comment: @YourAverageEuler Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In response to your comment. Calculus was historically formulated in terms of infinitesimals. That is, numbers that are infinitely small, that is where this notation, due to Liebnitz, hails from.

The truth of the matter is there are no infinitely small real numbers. It's possible to create an extension of the real numbers, called the hyperreal numbers, that have infinitesimals and define calculus in that way, but it's not a trivial development and there's not much gained from doing it.

Modern calculus is formulated in terms of limits, not infinitesmals. This notation has stuck around because sometimes it can be mnemonically/heuristically useful.

It's good for expressing the chain rule $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \, \frac{du}{dx}$$.

Also, sometimes we can treat them algebraically as real numbers, (like separating variables when solving simple differential equations), but these methods have to be formally justified. Doing something like taking the absolute value of a differential is ambiguous and makes little sense.

Next time, your professor tells you to think of an infinitesimal change in something, just interpret that as simply meaning very small. If you ever need to further clarify something about this please msg me below.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed discussion @DavidReed. The exact words of my math professor while introducing us to the chain rule -".....So this is the chain rule, the $du$'s just cancel giving us $\frac{dy}{dx}$....". Like seriously...and now it so happens the same person teaches us physics (I'm in high school) and he does crazy stuff like $\frac{du}{dt} = R$, so $\frac{dt}{du}=\frac{1}{R}$. It's the teaching that has to blamed for such twisted concepts.

Comment: @YourAverageEuler Not sure about the R, but he's effectively expressing the inverse function theorem, which says, under certain conditions, $ f^{-1}'(x) = 1/f'(x) $. The negative one there refers to the inverse function, not the $-1$ power.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @DavidReed Here R was some function (I can't remember, but we were doing it in thermodynamics). An also 'separation of variables' a more fancy (or more technical?) way of saying that we cross-multiplied the $dx$'s and $dy$'s throughout our differential equation?

Comment: @YourAverageEuler Yes. The name of the technique is "separation of variables".

Answer (score 1):

Those are **completely different things**.

Let's consider for example $y=x$, then:

$|x|'=-1$ for $x<0$ and $|x|'=1$ for $x>0$

whereas:

$|x'|=1$ for all $x$

**NOTE**

If with the notation

$$\frac{|d\vec v|}{dt}$$ you mean the derivative of the speed, the two things are also completely different (EG think to a circular motion at constant speed).

Comment: About your first argument: you are not considering $|dy|$, but $d|y|$, where $y(x) = x$. If we set $|dy| := d|y|$ then I agree with you, otherwise we should make the definition of $|dy|$ clear. Can you please say a couple of words about this point?

Comment: Have you assumed $\frac{|dy|}{dx} = \frac{d|y|}{dx}$ ? I am not sure what the former means but its obviously not that.

Comment: I can't imagine what other else it could be! Maybe we can ask to @YourAverageEuler more infomration on this. Thanks.

Comment: This is why I hate physicists. They poison the innocent minds of their students with thoughts of infitesimals and the like and then we're the ones that have to try and get them to unlearn that perspective.

Comment: @DavidReed This is exactly the problem I face. Studying physics and mathematics simultaneously has let me conclude that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a fraction, but only so in limited number of cases. Its very confusing when on one hand you're told that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a fraction of infinitesimals, but on the other hand we're told that $\frac{d}{dx}$ is an 'operator'. So convenient.

Comment: Ok I'll write something up